# Automatically creating class instances

Tags: objective-c, variables, instantiation

Is it possible to create dynamically instances of a class giving them specific names (e.g. Friend1, Friend2, etc)?

I have a "Friends" class with some instance variables (e.g. Name and Surname). In my app user selects from a list the number of "Friends" he wants to add. So in case he selects 5 the UITableView will be populated with 10 empty fields (Name and Surname).

Do you know any way to create these objects "on the fly"?

Comment: can't you use an array?

Comment: An array of already instantiated objects?

Comment: Could you give an example of what exactly you are after? if the user selects N items, create a mutable array and fill it with N new items and let the user fill the data ...

Comment: That's what a "computer program" does, or so I'm told.

Answer (score 0):

When he selects 5, create an array of friends:

```
friends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    [friends addObject:[[[Friend alloc] init] autorelease]];
[tableView reload];
```

(where `friends` NSMutableArray is declared in interface section of your view controller)

And in UITableViewDataSource:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == friendsSection)
        return [friends count] * 2;
    else ...;
}
```

I leave `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation as an exercise to the reader, it depends on too many details you didn't describe.

Comment: My example does not utilize proper resource management and probably other details are missing, of course.

Comment: I thought that I needed to know the names of the objects in order to store user input.

Comment: You may treat `friends[n]` as a name of object, if you want think that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is solved, good! But your question addressed also a problem that is not yet solved: "to create dynamically instances of a class **giving them specific names**", so that you can refer to them later using these **names**.
Referring to an object essentially means to send it a message. In the Objective-C runtime, this is done using `objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)`. Thus you need a pointer to `theReceiver`. I interpret you question so as "is it possible to associate the pointer to a new instance with a dynamically created name. I think this is possible using a dictionary like so:
You create dynamically your identifier: `NSString *myIdentifier = @"anyString";` or any other way to create a string. Then you create an instance of your class: `MyClass *myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];` or any other way to instantiate it. Eventually you establish the association: `NSDictionary *dict = @{myIdentifier: myObject};`
Later you can send the object a message, using the object's name as `[[dict objectForKey:myIdentifier] message]`;
Maybe there is an easier way to do it...